# The upload path does not appear to be valid in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, file-upload

facing problem while trying to upload files

Presently I am working on amazon ec2 server:

```
            $path ='../../../../assets/Data/';

            $config['upload_path'] = $path;
            $config['allowed_types'] = '*';
            $config['overwrite'] = true;
            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
            {
                    echo  $this->upload->display_errors();

                    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

            }
            else{  // I want to perform some action}
```

When I am trying to perform this action. I am getting an error message which says 
 **"The upload path does not appear to be valid".** Where as I have that path present in my CodeIgniter folder present on my server

Answer (score 0):

Is the `'../../../../assets/Data/'` directory's file permissions set to **777**, as suggested by the [Codeigniter User Guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html)?

Also, is the config being set in a config file or loaded with the library like this `$this-load->library('upload', $config);`

Lastly, to be extra sure that the path is correct, can you check the value of `var_dump(realpath('../../../../assets/Data/'));` in the same file as your code?

Answer (score 0):

Here example of path. I have folder in application name files and in files I have folder again name contracts-csv. Thats the path I make.

```
$config['upload_path']   = './files/contracts-csv/'; //Example path
```

Also you have missing code for load library.

```
$this->load->library('upload', $config);//its very need to work the code
```

And this code for uploading

```
$this->upload->data();//
```

...Hope I help you

Answer (score 0):

The problem usually occurs when a call to `$this->load->library('upload', $config);` , may be it does not load the configuration settings, so try adding the following statement after loading the upload library.

```
$this->upload->initialize($config);
```

Answer (score 0):

File Uplaod function takes a file system path.. SO ../../../../assets/Data/ not a valid path for uplaod file to file system..you can use 
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/Your upload folder path here starts from your project root directry';

Try This One..